# IE11 shows all text as bold after updating Google Font

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, fonts, google-fonts

**Background:** In an internal web app I am using the Google font, Open Sans. I have the font file downloaded and bundled with the app (the app has to work offline). Recently I noticed Google had a newer version of the font, at which point I re-downloaded it and updated it in the app. At this time I also changed the way I include the font in my CSS, dropping it to just use the .woff and .woff2 formats (only need to support IE11 and Chrome)

**Problem:** Since this update on my own computer on our test server, in IE only, all text is shown looking bold. In Chrome it is fine. In IE when looking at it in my local copy with localhost, the font works fine. On other computers it works fine all the time. I've only seen one other computer so far have the same issue.

If I inspect element, it is correctly set to use `font-weight: 400` and correctly uses the .woff file for IE11. It just seems to be using the bold version of the font instead of the regular version.

I am worried this is happening to a lot more of my client's computers now that I know it is not just mine only.

**Code:** The below is the code I use to import the font. The only difference between this and what I had before is that I'm no longer importing SVG and other formats.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(../assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.woff2?v=1.5.0) format('woff2'), url(../assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.woff?v=1.5.0) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('Open Sans SemiBold'), local('OpenSans-SemiBold'), url(../assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBold.woff2?v=1.5.0) format('woff2'), url(../assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBold.woff?v=1.5.0) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(../assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold.woff2?v=1.5.0) format('woff2'), url(../assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold.woff?v=1.5.0) format('woff');
}
```

**More details:** The web app uses Angular 5 (using the Angular CLI), SASS, and gets deployed via Jenkins on a Tomcat Windows server. The test server is currently being ran in development mode.

I have already tried to clear all the cache in my browser and have restarted my computer several times, but nothing fixes it.

I unfortunately can't link to the app as it is internal only.

Below is a screenshot of the differences when viewed on the test server and when on localhost:

[image: app-comparison]

I think this could be the result of any number of things so if I need to provide additional information please let me know.

Comment: to help debug in IE, first go Tools>Internet Options>Advance tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Now when you first open the dev tool its console will list errors for blocked content and security issues. Also the File>Properties menu in IE will tell you which IE security zone your localhost and server hosts map to.. they may not be what you expect... Intranet sites (that map to the IE Intranet zone) have restrictions... you should be targeting developing for the INternet security zone.

Comment: The DOM Explorer tab of the dev tool (f12) should tell you which font-face rule is applied (right panel).... IE also has accessibility settings for 'ignore font styles specified on web pages"... (General tab of Internet Options, Accessibility button)

Comment: @RobParsons Thanks for the help, unfortunately none of that solves the issue.